# How to create list of dropdowns, each displaying a pre-selected object from a subset array, but having a superset array of object options

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a subset list of chosen operations, currentOps. i have another superset list of all operations, jsonOperations, that contains all chosen operations.

I want to display each item in currentOps as pre-selected in its own dropdown, but the user can change each value of currentOps to any item from jsonOperations using each dropdowns' lists.

My attempt so far:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(currentOp, index) in currentOps" :key="currentOp">
        <td>
          <b-form-select name="status" class="fields-dropdown" v-model="currentOps[index]"> 
            <option v-for="(jsonOperation, optionIndex) in jsonOperations" :key="optionIndex" :value="jsonOperation">
                {{ jsonOperation.name }}: {{ jsonOperation.type }} - {{ jsonOperation.active ? 'active' : 'inactive' }}
            </option>
          </b-form-select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
data() {
    return {
      jsonOperations: [],
      currentOps: [],
    }
  },
</script>
```

currentOps array of objects, followed by an object item in jsonOperations array:
[image: structure]

What it looks like right now:
[image: what it looks like right now]

What I want it to look like upon loading page:
[image: What I want it to look like upon loading page]

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
  <div v-for="(currentOp, i) in currentOpNames" :key="i">
    <b-form-select class="fields-dropdown" v-model="selectedOptions[i]">
      <option v-for="(jsonOp, j) in jsonOperations" :key="jsonOp.id" :value="jsonOp.id">
        {{ jsonOp.name }}
      </option>
    </b-form-select>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      currentOpNames: [],
      jsonOperations: [],
      selectedOptions: [],
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.selectedOptions = this.currentOpNames.map(id => {
      const match = this.jsonOperations.find(op => op.id === id);
      return match ? match.id : null;
    });
  }
};
</script>
```